# C# WPF - What's this weird line that's showing up in Tooltip?

Tags: c#, wpf

I styled my Tooltip using this lines of C# code:

```
Popup pp = new Popup();
ToolTipService.SetShowDuration(pp, 1000);
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock() { Text = errorMessage };
tb.Foreground = SystemColors.InfoTextBrush;
tb.Background = SystemColors.InfoBrush;
tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
tb.Padding = new Thickness(4, 0, 4, 0);
tb.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

Border b1 = new Border() { Child = tb };
pp.Child = b1;
b1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);
b1.BorderBrush = SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush;

pp.Height = 20;
pp.PlacementTarget = this;
pp.StaysOpen = false;
```

And when the Tooltip get rendered, it looks like this

[image]

Does anyone knows why's that line is showing? and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Did you debug to check what is the value of "errorMessage " ?

Comment: @AnuViswan The value is errorMessage is either "Invalid Entry" or $"Entry value should be less than {maxValue}", maxValue is either 24 hours or 60 minutes according to the selection position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rendering issue. Usually set `UseLayoutRounding=true` solves the issue.

```cs
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock() { Text = errorMessage,  UseLayoutRounding = true };
```

[FrameworkElement.UseLayoutRounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding?view=netframework-4.8)